# How to set an email alert if we fill in custom date field other than todays date?

Tags: custom

```
trigger testtrigger on student_academics__c (after insert) {
    student_academics__c newupdate = trigger.new[0];
    Messaging.SingleEmailMessage email = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
    list <student_academics__c> sa = [select id, Name, Date__c, parentemail__c,overall_result__c from student_academics__c];
    for (student_academics__c s:sa)
    {
        if(s.Date__c == system.today())
            email.setToAddresses(new string[] {'parentemail__c'});
         email.setplaintextbody ('Todays date is ... ' + 'Date__c');
    }
}
```

Comment: Whom should be the email sent to? If it is to be sent to a related user (say owner of the record) _OR_ any specific email address _OR_ an email field on the same record, this can be achieved by using workflow.

Comment: It should be sent to user of the same record.      Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use not equal to operator to meet condition as

```
student_academics__c newupdate = trigger.new[0];
Messaging.SingleEmailMessage email = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();


list <student_academics__c> sa = [select id, Name, Date__c, parentemail__c,overall_result__c from student_academics__c];
for (student_academics__c s:sa)
{
    if(s.Date__c  != null && s.Date__c != system.today())
        email.setToAddresses(new string[] {'parentemail__c'});
     email.setplaintextbody ('Todays date is ... ' + 'Date__c');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of going for a trigger, this can be achieved by a workflow with email alert as an action.

Workflow Documentation: [Workflow Help](https://help.salesforce.com/htviewhelpdoc?id=customize_wf.htm&siteLang=en_US)

Email Alert Documentation: [Email Alert Actions](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=customize_wfalerts.htm&language=en_US)

You will need to create an email template to achieve this, [click here](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=creating_custom_html_email_templates.htm&language=th) to get information about HTML email templates.

Hope this helps.

Best Regards!